# With git, how to save/pause a ongoing big rebase to do something else, then go back to it?

Tags: git

So I have started to rebase a big branch on my current master (75 commits). I know it will take me a day or so. In the meantime, I need to address some comments on another PR.

How can I suspend my current rebase to amend my PR without re-cloning the repo or copying the folder (these would work of course)? Is this even possible?

Comment: There is no such git rebase option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no built-in way to "pause" a rebase that I know of, although you can certainly accomplish something like it with enough git finesse.

However, in the case you've described, a much simpler solution is simply to do your rebase in one working directory, and do the other changes you need to do in a different working directory.

To get a new working directory, you can either:

- Use a simple `git clone` to get a new working directory (AND a local repository, so you'll need to push/pull your results pack the original working directory).
- Or, take a look at `git worktree`, which can help you manage multiple worktrees using the exact same repository data.

Comment: Nice! `git worktree` does the job perfectly! It's not exactly what I wanted, but it is still a lot better than to re-clone a complete repo.

Comment: Commenting again after 2 years to say that git worktree are now a very important part of my day-to-day workflow, so thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh my god! I've never come across `git worktree` before, but after reading this answer and doing 10 minutes of research... I can't believe I haven't heard of it before! It could have saved me so much stress! Thank you for this question and answer!

Comment: 20 years of development and just now learning of this. So many bits wasted.